# dedicated instrucions for HI and LO registers in mips

Tags: assembly, mips

Why do we need dedicated instructions for accessing `HI` and `LO` registers? For example `mfhi $s0`. Why we don't use `add $s0 , $zero , Hi`?

Answer (score 2):

> why we don't use `add $s0 , $zero , Hi`?

Because MIPS uses a fixed instruction width (4 bytes per instruction), which limits the number of opcode / operand combinations you can encode. The register operand fields are 5 bits wide, which means that you can specify any of 32 registers, which happens to be the 32 general-purpose registers.